# circular dependency control in OCAML

Tags: compiler-construction, dependency-injection, module, ocaml, circular-dependency

**[EDIT]**

Thank you for your answer, my problem is the following :

**Module A called Map.ml**

```
let lst = ref [Instance1_ModuleB; Instance2_ModuleB; ...];;
let is_coliding p = DoSomeWork_And_Return_A_Bool ;;
.... other things here.
```

**Module B called Player.ml**

```
Open Map
class player_object (x_in, y_in, name_in)=

object (self)

method jump () =
       if Map.is_colliding self then
             DoSomeThing ();;
....
```

Any clue how to make that works.

**By the way, how do other programming languages hundle that? I never care about such dependency in C#!!!!!**
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your module A only need type from module B and no value, then you can create a moduleB.mli with the interface of module B, and compile it before moduleA:

moduleA.ml:

```
let foo (bar : ModuleB.bar) = bar.baaz
```

moduleB.mli:

```
class bar : object
  method baaz : int
  method buz : int
end
```

moduleB.ml

```
class bar =
object(s)
  method baaz = 3
  method buz = ModuleA.foo s
end
```

But if you have circular dependency on value or function it there is no simple solution, as for example for :

moduleA.ml:

```
let li = [new bar; new bar]

let foo (bar : ModuleB.bar) = bar.baaz
```

One can try to break such a circular dependency by using reference or mutable value in general:

moduleA.ml:

```
let li = [new bar; new bar]

let foo (bar : ModuleB.bar) = bar.baaz
let _ = ModuleB.initB foo
```

moduleB.ml

```
let foo = ref (fun x -> (failwith "not initialized" : int))

class bar =
object(s)
  method baaz = 3
  method buz = !foo s
end

let initB f = foo := f
```